# Vue - How to maintain a data flow from grandparent to grandchild?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
Vue.component('grandchild', {
  template: '<div>grandchild - {{ data2.value }}</div>',
  props: [ 'data2' ]
});

Vue.component('child', {
    template: '<div>child - {{ data1.id }}<grandchild v-bind:data2="data2"></grandchild></div>',
  props: [ 'data1' ],
  data () {
    return {
        data2: {
        value: this.data1.id
      }
    };
  }
});

let v = new Vue({
    el: '#div',
  data: {
    data1: {
        id: 3
    }
  }
});

setInterval(function () {
    v.data1.id++;
}, 1000);
```

v passes 'data1' to child via props,

child passes 'data2' to grandchild via props, data2.value = data1.id

See the setInterval function, it increases data1.id every second

But only child's dom updates

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xfgzwjef/1/

Someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data as calculated from the initial value of the prop in the child component isn't actually being updated, as there's nothing changing it. It's disassociated from the prop upon creation.

What you want is for `data2` to be computed, so it actually depends on the prop passed initially.

```
computed: {
  data2() {
    return {value: this.data1.id}
  }
}
```